# External JS not working in my html file?

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink, external

I'm pretty new to JavaScript, I am trying to execute my external JS to html, what im trying to do is to see if the mouseover responds when my mouse hovers one img.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>GWW- A Global Warming Warning...</title>

    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div class="gridContainer clearfix">
<div class="world">
  <img src="poluicao/poluicao0001.png" alt="Mundo">
     <div class="botao1">
       <img src="poluicao/offbuton.png" alt="but1">
     </div>
     <div  class="botao2">
       <!--<a href="#" >//-->
       <img  id="readybotao"  src="degelo/offbutton.gif"  alt="but2">
      <!-- </a> //-->
     </div>
  </div>

  </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="javascript.js"</script>

  </body>

  </html>
```

And this is my JS file:

```
function buttonon() {
alert("If it showed up it worked!");
}

  document.getElementById('readybotao').addEventListener("onmousover",buttonon());
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I see '>' missing here `<script src="javascript.js"<` is it the same in your code as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change external javascript like this :

```
var ele = document.getElementById("readybotao");
ele.addEventListener("mouseover",buttonon);
function buttonon() {
alert("If it showed up it worked!");
}
```

and close tag script :

```
 <script src="javascript.js"></script>
```

Comment: @Andre FIlipe you must change javascript code, if no change ,your code not working.

Comment: thank you very much, so everytime i want to change something on my html with JS i have to make a variable first?

Comment: @Andre FIlipe ,yes,variable must declare Above function.if my answer help you,accept my answer please.

Comment: But what if i want to change the gif on that img when i hover? do i write src ="" on the function?or there is another way to do it?

Comment: @Andre FIlipe و Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

you have `>`missing  on the line `<script src="javascript.js"</script>`

Comment: Thank you, I did not notice that